# Where can I find the data for income, equity, assets and sales of a company that is presented in terms of U.S. and outside of US.?

Tags: reference-request

I need to find the income, sales, equity and assets of Microsoft, Google and Apple for U.S. and outside of U.S. I see these information in the income stamens as a whole. But I need to know how much it is for the U.S. and how much it is for outside of U.S. I've been able to see in the annual report of Microsoft such a division for income and sales. But the other two isn't there. None of those are also available in Google's annual report. Can somebody please let me know where should I look?

Comment: If you haven't already, you might also want to ask this on https://opendata.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the [Mergent](https://www.mergentonline.com/login.php) database?  If you're part of a University system, Mergent is a typical offering through University libraries.  Your University librarian should be able to help you find and navigate it if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

this is a good source of data for countries all around the world: https://www.thomsonreuters.com/en/products-services/government/market-data-and-analytics.html